# I want to combine the **Sort and Filter** and **Toggle** Functions

Tags: powerapps

Can anyone show me how to combine the **Sort and Filter** and **Toggle** functions below. Each works fine with my Gallery separately but I do not know how to combine them.

**Sort and Filter:**

```
SortByColumns(
    Filter(
        Project_Gantt_Chart,
        Project = Dropdown7.Selected.Result

    ),
    "Start_Date",
    If(
        SortDescending1,
        Descending,
        Ascending
    )
)
```

**Toggle:**

```
If(
    ToggleComplete.Value = true,
    Filter(
        Project_Gantt_Chart,
        Percent_Complete2 < 100
    ),
    Project_Gantt_Chart
)
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to hide the projects with 100% complete when your toggle is active, correct me if I'm wrong.

This code should work:

```
SortByColumns(
If(
    ToggleComplete.Value,
    Filter(
        Project_Gantt_Chart,
        Project = Dropdown7.Selected.Result && Percent_Complete2 < 100
    ),
    Filter(
        Project_Gantt_Chart,
        Project = Dropdown7.Selected.Result
    )
),
"Start_Date",
If(
    Sortdescending1,
    Descending,
    Ascending
)
```

)

Let me know if this solves your problem,
Best Regards